# Make a web application compatible with handheld

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, handheld

I'm developing a web app, with a full ajax ui using html, css and jquery as the js framework.
All pages are developed for PC, but there are some pages that should work fine on Handheld (windows ce) as well. Along with css changes to make those pages compatible with handheld devices, there are little operational differences in js. i.e user does not select dates in handheld whilst they can on pc.

The question is, have can I make different pages for the handheld version? How can I develop compatible and ready pages only by applying another css file? Does @media help? Should i use jquery mobile? Can I detect the device using js and switch the css and some logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use pure CSS and the `media` attribute of the `<link>` tag to control which stylesheet is loaded. [This guy](http://www.bushidodesigns.net/blog/mobile-device-detection-css-without-user-agent/) seems to have some nice cross-browser markup that will get you started.

Alternatively/additionally, consider using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to add classes to your root `<html>` node that tell you a lot of information about the capabilities of a user. Then you can do simple tests in Javascript to enable or disable certain features if certain functionality isn't present.

Comment: question! i'm using jquery, isn't it possible to use jQuery instead of modernizer framework? i prefer not to use multiple js framework.

Comment: @Reza: modernizr isn’t really a framework like jQuery — it only helps you detect support for HTML5 and CSS3 features (which jQuery doesn’t do). So there isn’t any overlap between jQuery and Modernizr.

Comment: so, i want to support ie 6.0 for windows mobile ce. there is no html5, no css3. is @media enough to change css? or should or develop same pages with another css and js?
i want to do something like this:
if the devise is handheld, remove some fields and use another css.

Comment: Yes, in that case you would use IE conditional comments to only include a specific CSS file reference if using a mobile device (with @media attribute) and IE 6. That stylesheet would hide some fields by setting them to `display: none;`.

Comment: great! so i can restyle my page using css and remove additional fields using .remove() or .replace() methods of jQuery. but i'm wondering how to detect the mobile browser in js.

Comment: @Reza You don't even need to use `.remove()` or `.replace()` in jQuery - just hide them using a CSS rule that makes them `display: none;`.

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to detect a if user has a mobile device in Javascript. Not sure if Modernizr can do it, or if there is a way in pure jQuery. If all else fails, in your server side code, detect the user agent and if it is a mobile browser, set a class on your `<html>` tag, much like Modernizr does, and check for that class in Javascript: `if ($('html').hasClass('mobile-browser')) { ... }`.